# Set element href to other element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu and I need to set the href of each menu item as the content item ids, something like this:

```
$(this).attr("href") = $(".element").attr("id");
```

How can I?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how can I ? That isn't right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("href",$(".element").attr("id"));
```

Comment: note that you seems used class as id, use id instead `element` class

Comment: yeah the class is needed for something else, you actually pointed to another question I have tho. I'll be writing it down and post it in another stack. Will link it here in a moment. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741545/assign-new-id-for-each-element-dynamically

Answer (score 3):

To change the href, use something like this:

```
$("a").attr("href", $(".element").attr("id"))
```

Good luck.

Comment: @rob.m -- no problem, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple menu items, you can use jquery's each function:

```
$(".yourMenuItemsSelector").each(function(){

    $(this).attr("href",$(".element").attr("id"));

});
```