# Create new unique ids for each element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, I am doing various things but what I am now looking at is that fact that I am assigning to each menu item href the same name as per the id name of each element I am creating.

```
$(".nav li a").on("click", function(e) {
$(this).attr("href",$(".span6").attr("id"));
$('#content').removeAttr('id');

var $row = $(".span9");
var $rowNew = $('.new');

if ($rowNew.children().length > 1) {
        $(".span9 div").removeClass("new");
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
}

if ($(".new").length == 0) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
        $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
} else {
    $('<div id="content" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
}

});
```

This is how I am assigning to each menu item href the same name as per the id name of each element I am creating:

```
    $(this).attr("href",$(".span6").attr("id"));
```

I now need to create a new unique id name for each `<div id="content" class="span6"></div>`

I know it has already an id called `#content` but I am removing that on a click using `$('#content').removeAttr('id');`

How do I generate new unique ids each time?

In another template using php i do: `<?php $a = 1; ?>` then `<div class="span6" id="<?php echo "i".$a; ?>">` in a loop then `<?php $a++; ?>` but about in my case with jquery?

Also I think I will need to do something in regards of the first and last `<div id="content" class="span6"></div>` as these will already have an id #content set, these ids are removed on the next click only at the moment so creating a new id will lead to have 2 ids for the first and last i guess.

Comment: the unix seconds since epoch would be a convenient number to base your id on. preprend it with any alphabet letter so it's a valid html id.

Comment: in another template using php i do: '<?php $a = 1; ?>' then '<div class="span6" id="<?php echo "i".$a; ?>">' in a loop then <?php $a++; ?> but about my case and jquery?

Comment: Are you sure you need all those ids and classes?

Comment: The classes, yes. The unique ids are to generate anchors for the menu and that's why I need to set the href equal to each id.

Comment: i don't think you need ids here at all, just keep newly created elements in array and refer to them, also to keep random data use `.data()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to test the first ID available.

```
function setId(elem)
{
    var first = 0;
    while($('#i'+first).length > 0) first++;
    elem.setAttr('id', 'i'+first);
}

//Usage:
setId(myJqueryObject);
```

Comment: how would I apply this to my case?

Comment: Maybe `setId($('#content'));` instead of `$('#content').removeAttr('id');` ? Tell me if it's not what you want to do, I may misunderstand where you need to put an unique ID.

Comment: I need to generate unique ids for <div id="content" class="span6"></div> BUT at FIRST i need to keep id=content. To be honest, all I need to do is to create href for my menu items so that I can anchor them to each box so I thought of creating unique ids but not only I don't know how to create unique ids, I also have the problem that I already have an id (I use ajax which loads stuff into #content and then I remove the id #content on a click, so it's fine as I won't ever have 2 #content). The issue is generating anchors tho

Comment: I think your href value is missing a #: `$(this).attr("href",'#'+$(".span6").attr("id"));`.